# PayPal IPN issue for notify

Tags: vb.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have set up a PDT form and that is working and collecting payments and then returning to the appropriate url with the follow parameters

tx=1************X&st=Completed&amt=0.02&cc=GBP&cm=&item_number=NA

I am using the follow example code:

```
Dim strSandbox As String = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
    Dim strLive As String = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(strLive), HttpWebRequest)

    'Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Dim Param() As Byte = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength)
    Dim strRequest As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param)
    strRequest = strRequest & "&cmd=_notify-validate"
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length

    'for proxy
    'Dim proxy As New WebProxy(New System.Uri("http://url:port#"))
    'req.Proxy = proxy

    'Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    Dim streamOut As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)
    streamOut.Write(strRequest)
    streamOut.Close()
    Dim streamIn As StreamReader = New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim strResponse As String = streamIn.ReadToEnd()
    streamIn.Close()

    If strResponse = "VERIFIED" Then
        'check the payment_status is Completed
        'check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        'check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
        'check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        'process payment
        lit1.Text = "verified"
    ElseIf strResponse = "INVALID" Then
        'log for manual investigation
        lit1.Text = "invalid"
    Else
        'Response wasn't VERIFIED or INVALID, log for manual investigation
        lit1.Text = "unknown"
    End If
    lit1.Text = lit1.Text & "<br /><br />" & strRequest.ToString
```

I am only getting an invalid response so I tried to see what was being sent to Paypal but its only sending &cmd=_notify-validate and not rest of the parameters.

So I manually added to the parameters but still only got invalid.

Could someone please assist with what I am missing? The payment was successful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it, I didnt understand the process but do now